# Firefox resizing browser window focus changes to another part of the page

Tags: firefox, browser

I am reading various tutorials online as well as online books from O'Reilly Safari online, splitting my screen in half with the left half having a code editor window and right half browser.  Sometimes I expand my browser window for the full screen so I can look at a diagram or code snippet closely but then the browser scrolls to a totally different part of the web page I am looking at to fit the larger window.  It does the same when I resize back from full to half the screen split vertically.  This is really annoying since I have to scroll up or down to find the line I was reading every time.
Is there any way to prevent this on Firefox or are there other browsers which are smarter?  Ie. knows to put the part I am reading in the resized window.

Comment: What OS? Mac OS? In Windows, I do not see that behavior. It might also be peculiar to the O'Reilly text - try another site.

Comment: Hi it is on Ubuntu 20.04, and it also happens on the Oracle Apex tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

So, this does not happen in Chrome and as much as I like the relative privacy I get from using Duckduckgo on Firefox, things like this and the fact that Firefox frequently just does not open properly, I am going back to Chrome for things like this.

Comment: Never had a problem with Firefox opening properly on  Windows or on Ubuntu. Perhpas it's a peculiarity of your installation; try uninstalling Firefox and creating a new profile, as Mozilla recommends. You might also consider the *open source* Chromium browser, native to Linux, https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-chromium-web-browser-on-ubuntu-20-04/ , instead of Google's proprietary Chrome.